# KineticJS & IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, canvas, internet-explorer-9, kineticjs

I'm trying to figure out why creating a canvas using KineticJS isn't working on my site in IE9. This example: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/kineticjs/html5_canvas_kineticjs_path/ works perfectly in IE9, but when I copy/paste the source code into a file on my site...it doesn't work at all (it does work in FF/Safari/Chrome though).

Is there some server settings I should be checking? I know the rendering is all on the client, but I can't figure out why it works one place and not the other.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you don't have Compatibility Mode on...

[image: Compatibility Mode]

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that it automatically turned compatibility view on when looking at internal sites.

Answer (score 1):

I have just now found that Mr ericdrowell said in Github :

"I don't believe that there are any 2d canvas libraries which are also compatible with excanvas. If you're requirement is to use a graphics library which works in all browsers, you might consider going with Raphael.js, which has an SVG and VML renderer, but is much slower and less feature rich than a canvas library."

it's sad :(

Answer (score 0):

For enabling compatible mode press f12 in your ie9 change

Browser mode ie9  Document Mode:IE 9 Standards